# Change the default name of relationship in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a ManyToMany relationship follow as:

```
class Subtopic(models.Model):
   id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'Subtopic'

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
   qid = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
   subtopics = models.ManyToManyField(Subtopic)

   class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'Question'
```

In the admin interface, I would like to change the default names in this picture.

http://flic.kr/p/apx3j8

The first name is the relationship of two class such as Subtopic and Question.
Second is the name of Subtopic class.
And finally is Question class

Django model automatically generates an intermediary table namely Question_Subtopics and I can not meddle in this table.

Please help me to achieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

that text is filled with `__unicode__`, which is similar to java's toString().

```
class Subtopic(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Just do that, and you'll be fine :)

Comment: Thank fceruti. However, it is not correctly. I have also filled with __unicode__ but it doesn't affect to the default name.